# How do I get assimp to work in Opengl with C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, assimp

I have been trying to get the library Assimp to work in my project, but at every point I keep running into problems. I can't find any information on coding with the Assimp library and am stuck trying to even link it to my project.

Right now trying to link Assimp to my project gives me this error:

Error 3 error MSB3073: The command "copy "Debug\SimpleOpenGL.exe" ..\bin copy ....\bin\assimp_debug-dll_Win32\Assimp32d.dll ..\bin

:VCEnd" exited with code 1. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 113

Any idea what this error is? I really don't understand it.

Comment: The error tells you that visual studio was unable to copy the Assimp32d.dll library to your output folder. How does the command look like that you added to your "Custom Build Steps" or to "Build Events"

Comment: @BDL Looking in Build Events I see those lines there. How does that section work though? I have never seen it before and really don't understand it

Comment: This are normal batch commands that are executed somewhere during the build process. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e85wte0k.aspx).

Comment: @BDL I didn't understand that at all, but I was able to make a new project and include Assimp without that weird error. My problem now is I can't find a tutorial or code for Assimp that works properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: I use Assimp for loading of static meshes in my engine here: https://github.com/LloydGhettoWolf/2014OpenGLEngine/tree/master/opengltest

The StaticMesh class is where you can see some code that loads a mesh. You should check Ogldev tutorials for how-tos on loading static meshes and also animating them

Comment: @LloydCrawley I was able to get part of Ogldev tutorial to work. It will load my model correctly, but I am having trouble getting a texture to load. There is just so much inheritance in it that it is very difficult to follow. I also don't want to just copy/paste the whole engine. I am having trouble understanding the code they made in the tutorial. I did look at your code as well, but am afraid to say I am having trouble understanding it as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: @WhyYouNoWork Hi. What kind of mesh are you trying to load? An .obj file? A .MD2 file? etc?